# Does the inverse element of a group also have to be under the same set of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

In other words, lets say there is a group $G$. If there is an element $g\in G$, by definition there has to be an inverse $g^{-1}$. Now, my question is, does $g^{-1}$ have to be an element $\in G$? Sorry if this may sound obvious but I want to make sure as the definition doesn't specifically state this.

Comment: Yes, always and forever.

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing this definition.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: If your definition doesn't specifically state this, then I would very much like to see exactly what it says.

Comment: Arthur and Randall: it's probably just a less formal definition, along the lines of "each element $g$ has an inverse $g^{-1}$", where the condition that $g^{-1} \in G$ is implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the following is from [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) of Group (mathematics):

For each $a$ in $G$, **there exists an element $b$ in $G$**, commonly denoted $a^{−1}$ (or $−a$, if the operation is denoted "$+$"), such that $a \cdot b = b \cdot a = e$, where $e$ is the identity element.

Answer (score 1):

Since the group operation is only required to be on $G$, to make sense of $g \cdot g^{-1}$, we must have $g^{-1} \in G$.